# How to logout user in asp.net core web API with jwt and identity framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

**Hi**
I Create API in asp.net core with JWT.
I want to create API endpoint for logout user with identity framework and jwt but not know how to logout user from API and logout from device where API end point call.
**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

To logout, we `clear the token from the local storage` of the browser. If using packages, you have an option to call logout method. Else you will have to manually clear the token

When using Jwt, we set an expiration time for the token. So, if the token expires, the token is invalidated. So, set a reasonable expiration time to begin with.

To be safe, keep a list of blacklisted token in the backend (DB or some cache like Redis) and validate if the token is valid on every request if you want to avoid someone using the key (got hand of the key while in browser) after you have cleared the cache and key has not expired.